# Magento 2.1.8- How to disable or remove images from all products in the frontend?

Tags: magento2, product-images

I don't want to show any **image**...**small, thumbnail or any on both catalog and product details page** at the frontend, and in the cart or in any other component. I'm using default theme - Luma and navigated to a path `<magento dir>/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/etc` and watched the file `view.xml` there. I want to remove or disable all the `<media>` and `<image>`, and `<var>` also has something like image gallery n image pan parameters. Is there anything programmatically or Layout xml from admin panel in the design it can disable? In the medicines or vaccination, you have nothing to display in the images, just a name is sufficient in the catalog display. So I want to remove the default Magento images.

Comment: try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40259303/add-remove-image-programmatically-to-product-magento2

Comment: really no idea which file need to be edit with the mentioned link. @Manoj Deswal